# How to decrease iOS app size xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

i have developed an iOS app and i'm using many 3rd party libraries suck as Google, Facebook, VLC ect, when i generate IPA i'm getting 92,5MB and when i upload it to appStore i get 200MB.
Is there a way to decrease it to arround 60MB ?

Comment: one way is that you can use On Demand resource but it is only for the resources if you are using. link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-on-demand-resources-on-ios-and-tvos--cms-24929

Comment: I'm using ressource but the framworks are the ones that have big sizes, any solution to reduce their size ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all optimisation switched on in Build Settings.
And yes, sometimes its easier to check library code on GitHub (if it open sourced) and implement necessary logic manually, that include whole library in the project. Swift projects quite bulky, need to keep all runtime libraries inside the app

Comment: I have already "Optimization level" set to "Fastest, Smallest"

Comment: the only way then to optimise resources (like using vector and smaller graphics) and cutting libraries where its possible. Nobody willing to download 200mb app :)